# (PowerShell) Log Exceptions and Continue (Active Directory Module)

Tags: powershell, exception, active-directory

I'm using [New-ADUser](http://ss64.com/ps/new-aduser.html) and Add-ADGroupMember

If the user already exists or is already in the group then the functions throw exceptions (which are expected and not a problem).

**How do I log the exceptions to file and keep going?**

- [Redirection](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-redirection.html) is not working - the exceptions always go to the
  console.
- -ErrorAction is not working - exceptions still go to the console
- Try / Catch works, but execution stops and the rest of the commands don't run
- I can do a Try / Catch for every single statment, but that seems
  ridiculous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish this is probably using the [`trap`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847742.aspx) construct:

```
function Test-Trap{
    trap {
        $_ | Out-String | Out-File C:\path\to\errors.txt -Append
    }

    Get-ADUser -NoSuchParam "argument"
    Write-Host "Show must go on"
    nonexistingcommand
    Write-Host "Still executing"
}
```

When you call `Test-Trap`, you'll see that after the error has been written to the console, the trap is executed, and the rest of the execution flow is resumed:

[image: Test-Trap screenshot]

And the error record output as it would normally appear on screen (courtesy of `Out-String`) has been saved to the file:

[image: resulting log file]

---

You could add cool features like timestamps and stack traces to your trap:

```
function Test-Trap{
    trap {
        $LogPath = "C:\path\to\errors.txt"
        $ErrorCount = $ErrorCount + 1
        $("[Error {0} trapped {1}]:" -f $ErrorCount,(Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")) | Out-File $LogPath -Append
        $_ | Out-String | Out-File $LogPath -Append
        if(($st = $_.Exception.Stacktrace)){ $st |Out-File $LogPath -Append }
        $("[Error {0} logged]" -f $ErrorCount)| Out-File $LogPath -Append
    }

    Provoke-Error -NoSuchParam muhahaha
}
```

[image: Trap log with stacktrace]

Comment: Thanks!  That is very helpful.  I hadn't thought of the timestamp so that is a nice bonus.

Comment: Glad to help. You can also safely use `$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"` inside a function to suppress the error in the console, without affection the global `$ErrorActionPreference` (see [`about_Scopes`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` with `-ErrorVariable`:

```psh
$e = $null
New-ADUser iExist -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable e
$e # contains the error
```

You can also use the built in `$Error` variable, which is a circular buffer holding all the errors.

```psh
$ErrorPreference = SilentlyContinue # I don't like this personally

New-ADUser iExist
Add-ADGroupMember iExist iForgotTheParameters

$Error[0] # The Add-ADGroupMember error
$Error[1] # The New-ADUser error
```

So you could set your `$ErrorPreference`, do a bunch of commands, and at the end of it all, do something like `$Error | Out-File -Path errors.txt`.

Have a look at [PowerShell Error Handling and Why You Should Care](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/12/powershell-error-handling-and-why-you-should-care.aspx) for more ideas.

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work.  The -ErrorAction and -ErrorVariable information shows up with the exception in the console though. $e is empty if I print it.

Comment: $Error has the messages, but I can't keep track of which error goes with which command.